# Human readable PostgreSQL 10 partition description

Tags: postgresql, metadata, partition

If I create a PostgreSQL 10 partition for a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement_y2006m01 PARTITION OF measurement
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2006-01-01') TO ('2006-02-01');
```

How can I recreate the DDL from the pg_catalog tables and views? The pg_class table has a relpartbound column, but its content is in an internal unreadable format.

Comment: It may be better to ask this at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pg_get_expr()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to get a readable version of the partition definition:

```
select pg_get_expr(c.relpartbound, c.oid, true) as partition_expression
from pg_class c
where relname = 'measurement_y2006m01';
```